# Is it possible to determine statistical independence of 2 random variables in this case?

Tags: statistics, independence

After a long and unfruitful discussion with a tutor, I decided to post the question here:

"Given 2 binary random variables with 
 $p(X = 0) = p(X = 1) = 0.5$ and 
$p(Y = 0) = p(Y = 1) = 0.5$, determine if X and Y are statistically independent of one another."

My approach:

In general, I would check if the following would be true: $p(x\cap y) =p(x) * p(y)$
But in my opinion the left part of the equation isn't given, therefor one cannot determine whether this is statistically independent or not.

Approach of the tutor:

Without a convincing argumentation, he thinks that in all 4 cases the intersections ($p(x\cap y)$) have to be $1/4$ and therefor X and Y are independent.

So I provided a counterexample, proving that $1/4$ isn't the only possible probability. For example  
$p(X = 0\cap Y = 0) = 0.2$ 
$p(X = 0\cap Y = 1) = 0.3$ 
$p(X = 1\cap Y = 0) = 0.3$ 
$p(X = 1\cap Y = 1) = 0.2$ 
 would also be possible and does not violate the initial information, since in every case they add up correctly to $0.5$.

Somehow the tutor (a PhD-student) thinks that this is not possible.

So the question would be: Who is right and why?

Comment: There is not enough information to determine if $X$ and $Y$ are independent of one another.  There is no reason to suspect that each of the cases has equal probability.  You are correct and he is wrong.  Your example is a perfectly valid one.  Another hopefully even more obvious example is where $X=Y$ or where $X=1-Y$... which requires even less effort to calculate.

Comment: Now... to be fair, just because the tutor is in a PhD program (*or has finished a PhD program?*) doesn't mean that probability is their focus and they may be very skilled in other areas... but if they are in a math PhD program, having at least introductory knowledge in most of the main areas of maths is par for the course so this is really quite embarrassing to have been so wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we let the probabilities in the 2x2 table be labeled $p_{00}$, $p_{01}$, $p_{10}$, and $p_{11}$, then with the marginals being

$$p_{00}+p_{01}=p_{00}+p_{10}=p_{10}+p_{11}=p_{01}+p_{11}=1/2$$

we also know that the individual cell probabilities must be no greater than 1/2:
$0\leq p_{ij}\leq 1/2$.  So set $p_{1,1}$ to some value between 0 and 1/2.  Then

$$p_{00}=p_{11}$$
$$p_{01}=1/2-p_{11}$$
$$p_{10}=1/2-p_{11}$$

Independence will only occur when $p_{11}=1/4$.

So to repeat what @JMoravitz stated: you are correct and the tutor is wrong.